# How can I get a correct publish date in TYPO3?

Tags: date, datetime, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7.6.9 and want to use the publish date and expiration date options for content elements in TYPO3, but currently this is not working correctly for me, because the time part seems to be incorrect.

For example:

If I set the publish date to: **18:00 04-09-2016** and the real time is **19:00 04-09-2016** then the element is not visible in frontend. For this reason I have checked some values and it seems that there is a two hour difference to the real time, because **17:00 04-09-2016** is working.

Furthermore I have set the timezone via install tool to UTC and I think that is the problem:

```
[SYS][phpTimeZone] = UTC
```

I have set the timezone to UTC because I got a two hour difference by using the timezone "Europe/Berlin" and different datetime objects in an extension. I could fix this by set the timezone to UTC, but now I got in trouble with the publish and expiration options.

Is there a solution to get both to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caveat here is that the **dates you enter in the backend are UTC**, not your local timezone. This is not sooo well documented, but trust me, I debugged that stuff last week ;-)

The dates are **stored in your server’s timezone**, so be cautious with changing the timezone after the fact—this **might break existing dates**!

The effect you observed is actually exactly what happens when you are in CEST (UTC+2):

1. you create a content element and set its publication time to 17:00 (UTC)
2. you visit the page at 17:01 CEST (15:01 UTC) -> the content is not visible
3. you visit the page at 19:01 CEST (17:01 UTC) -> the content is visible

Comment: So editors have to set the time always to UTC in the backend? Or will Claus answer fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, times entered in the backend unfortunately are always UTC. But we recently made the input fields timezone-aware, which is a first step to also display the timezone to editors and enable them to enter times in their local timezone. That will probably follow for TYPO3 8 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also define the time zone in PHP's configuration (`date.timezone`). You should also, but are not required to, properly set your system time zone.

Comment: This is actually **dangerous advice** if you already have dates stored in integer fields (= UNIX timestamps). These are treated to be in the server timezone (or rather the PHP-configured timezone), so changing the PHP timezone will change the interpretation of saved dates.

Comment: Server-level configuration of things like time zone and locale should of course be changed with great care, thanks for adding. I don't agree that it is "dangerous advise" to recommend doing/fixing proper configuration of the server but of course it doesn't hurt to know about the potential side effects.